# mapping rest responses with Jackson JSON

Tags: rest, jackson

I have a `REST` call that can return either `AccountPojo` or `ErrorCodePojo`. Each of these have specific fields. How can I use the `Jackson JSON` libary to easily parse the response and fetch `AccountPojo` or the `ErrorCodePojo`?

I have something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
   ret = mapper.readValue(json, AccountPojo.class);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
   ret = mapper.readValue(json, ErrorCodePojo.class);
}
```

but I don't think this is nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`ObjectMapper#convertValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class%29) method. With this method your parsing algorithm could look like this:

1. Deserialize JSON to `Map` class.
2. Check if map contains property from class `AccountPojo`/`ErrorCodePojo`.
3. Convert map to the target class.

For example, let's assume that your `ErrorCodePojo` class looks like this:

```
class ErrorCodePojo {

    private int errroCode;
    private String message;

    //getters, setters
}
```

Property `errroCode` exists only in `ErrorCodePojo`. `AccountPojo` does not contain this property.

```
// Step 1
Map<?, ?> value = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
// Step 2
if (value.containsKey("errroCode")) {
    // Step 3
    mapper.convertValue(value, ErrorCodePojo.class);
} else {
    // Step 3
    mapper.convertValue(value, AccountPojo.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looking good but could you tell me why you think this could be better than to catch exception on conversion error?

Comment: In my scenario you know what is the type of the JSON object and you do not have to think about exception. What if you have to deserialize more types? In my scenario you can add `else if(...)` statement. In yours - you have to add additional `try-catch` statements into catch block. I gave you an additional option. You should choose whether it is better for you or not. The best solution in this case is - JSON should contain information about type.