# Mapping Dynamic Json response(has changing attributes) using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo, objectmapper

I am trying to map Json response whose attributes changes if there is any error. For example:

valid response :

```
{
"Header":[{
             //some data 
          }],
"Component":[{
             //data 
                }],
"ServiceParameter":[{
           //data
      }]
}
```

error response:

```
{
    "Header":[{
                 //some data 
              }],
    "ErrorMessage":[{
                 //data 
                    }],
    "ServiceParameter":[{
               //data
          }]
    }
```

How can I map(with Jackson if possible) component data or error message for the given response ?

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of having both fields included in your POJO, like this:

```
class JsonResponse {
    @JsonProperty("Headers")
    private List<Header> headers;

    @JsonProperty("Component")
    private List<Component> components;

    @JsonProperty("ErrorMessage")
    private List<ErrorMessages> errorMessages;

    @JsonProperty("ServiceParameters")
    private List<ServiceParameters> serviceParameters;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

You can then know whether it's an error or not by checking if the errorMessages list is empty or not.

Jackson is a very flexible JSON (de)serializer, so it's very likely there's a way to do it, but this one is definitely the easiest one!

Comment: Thanks Kudama. I included both the fields. Earlier, while mapping I was getting null pointer exception as I could have mapped only one of those fields(ie component or error message).  Well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016713/6534932) was also helpful to me.